# Why is my Windows 10 computer preferring IPv4 over working IPv6?

Tags: networking, windows-10, ipv6

A Windows 10 computer on my network has a fully-functional IPv6 connection, but always prefers IPv4 when available. http://test-ipv6.com/ in Edge, Firefox, and Chrome reports "Your browser has real working IPv6 address - but is avoiding using it. We're concerned about this." I've never set this up this way, and I can't find any settings that would be causing it. Other computers, both Windows and Linux, exist on the same network but don't have this problem. In the Registry, under HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters, neither EnableICSIPv6 nor DisabledComponents exist, and this is the case both on this computer and on a properly functioning Windows 10 computer. What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is the result the same across multiple browsers? Note that web browsers prioritize addresses differently; in particular they try both IPv4 and IPv6 at once, and use whichever replies first.

Comment: Yes, it's the same. I edited that detail into my question.

Comment: What do you mean by " fully-functional IPv6 connection"? Do you have static/dynamic IPv6 address (not link-local IP)? Can you traceroute or ping any IPv6 address? Can you resolve websites with IPv6? Try this command `nslookup myip.opendns.com 2620:0:ccc::2` Do you get any IPv6 in output?

Comment: I have a real, global IPv6 address from my ISP. I can ping IPv6 Internet addresses. I can visit IPv6-only sites like loopsofzen.uk. That command resolves the name to my IPv6 address.

Comment: Does this only occur in a browser? What happens if you try pinging the same domain from the system, does ping prefer ipv6 or ipv4? This will help narrow this down as a browser vs. OS issue. Also, do other systems on the same network have the same problem? and are they running the same OS?

Comment: @BenFranske Other systems on the network, both Windows 10 and Linux, all work fine. I'll try the ping test tonight.

Comment: @BenFranske Ping is the same as the browsers. IPv6-only hosts work, but hosts that support both will use the IPv4 one.

Comment: Tricky. Windows, like most OSs will usually prefer IPv6 over IPv4. However, recent versions of Windows like Windows 10 are trying to be all smart and check the reliability of a connection before using it. It seems likely Windows has decided on that PC that IPv6 is unreliable so it is preferring IPv4. I'll need to leave advanced troubleshooting of that up to someone with more Windows fu than me.

Comment: One addition possibility I have thought of is to check whether the system has a different DNS server than others on the network (e.g. run `ipconfig /all` on a system which works and one which does not. Windows does some prioritization based on whether the DNS server is being accessed over IPv4 or IPv6 and is returning A or AAAA records to the query. It may be necessary to Wireshark the system and watch some DNS queries too.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, by default, Windows prefers IPv6 over IPv4.

**>In the Registry, under HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters, neither EnableICSIPv6 nor DisabledComponents exist.
If the registry entries do not exist, you can manually add them.**

You can fix it using the tool provided by Microsoft, or, manually editing the registry entries.

Details steps you may reference KB 929852 - How to disable IPv6 or its components in Windows:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929852/how-to-disable-ipv6-or-its-components-in-windows

Best Regards,
Eve Wang

Comment: Those keys don't exist on a computer that works fine, though, so I'm not sure that's it. I tried the fix-its to re-enable IPv6 and make it the default, but they didn't work.